# Induce compiler to avoid/trigger copies on rvalues

Tags: c++, optimization, copy

In the following code I have a function `foo` taking as argument a `std::function` returning a big object (here a `vector`) and uses it only to access its values. The big object may be built on-the-fly by `fun` or be a reference to an existing object as the two lambda expressions in the main show.

I would like to optimize this code to avoid useless copies possibly by choosing the right return type of the `std::function`.

If I use return by value, RVO optimizes out the copy and makes exactly what I want for the "build on-the-fly" case: no copies are done, the vector is built exactly where it needs to and later destroyed at the end of `foo`. However, in the second case the compiler does copy the vector even if I don't really need it. The second case would be the perfect situation for a return-by-reference but this would break the first case since reference to temporary are evil.

I understand that making `foo` directly taking a reference to the vector would solve the problem in this particular case but my use case is more complex. Is there a way to solve this?

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct myVec : public std::vector<double> {
    using std::vector<double>::vector;
    myVec(myVec const & v){
        std::cout << "Copy ctor\n";
        *this=v;
    }
};


void foo(std::function<myVec(void)> fun){
    for(auto & v : fun()){
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo([]()->myVec{return myVec(100,0.);});
    myVec existing(100,1.);
    foo([&existing]()->myVec{return existing;});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "reference to temporary are evil" -- why? What happens if you make a move ctor for `myVec`?

Comment: Just to clarify, this line: `foo([]()->myVec{return myVec(100,0.);});` is currently unoptimized, and `foo([&existing]()->myVec{return existing;});` (w/ lvalue reference) is?

Comment: The compiler will not optimize away anything until the compiler can prove that the optimization has no observable side effects. I see multiple reasons why the compiler might find it difficult to do so. It may be obvious to you and me, but we have a human brain, and the compiler does not.

Comment: Do you need a `vector` or maybe just a `tuple`?

Comment: @JonathanLam I think the move ctor is inherited from std::vector and this is the reason why no copy is done in the first case. For the second case, how would I manage the rvalue reference? I don't want "existing" to be moved, just to be referenced. Concerning the second comment, the problem is opposite. The line ``` foo([&existing]()->myVec{return existing;}); ``` copies the vector in foo.

Comment: @tadman vector is just an exemple of possibly "Big object". This may be a complex class containing multiple members

Comment: @Teloze I might have misunderstood. Try making the lambda expression return an lvalue reference? And so you're saying that  the rvalue one is already being moved, not copied?

Comment: @JonathanLam If I make lvalue reference, then the first case will break because the temporary object is created within ```fun``` and immediately destroyed.

Comment: Fair enough. In situations with a trivial number of members `std::tuple` may perform better. If this is some kind of large, expensive to copy object, use references if not one of the [pointer-wrappers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Answer (score 1):

`[&existing]()->myVec{return existing;}` return by copy, not by reference, so it would create copy.

You need so `[&existing]()->myVec&{return existing;}`.

Then issue is with `std::function`

so either provide 2 overloads (`void foo(std::function<myVec()>)` and `void foo(std::function<myVec&()>)`), or use template and get rid of std::function:

```
template <typename F>
void foo(F fun){
    for (const auto & v : fun()){
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. So a simple overload with the lvalue-returning lambda would do it!

Comment: The code I have is not really using ```std::function```. I just put it to make the code shorter. However, for testing, I already tried the overloading you suggest but the compiler is complaining about an ambiguous call to overloaded foo. Anyway, I really do like your templated version!